# Chrome Extension - How do i set column widths of Extension Popup

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to create a layout for a chrome extension popup and using

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
    1
</div>
<div class='col-md-4'>
    2
</div>
<div class='col-md-4'>
    3
</div>
```

Seems to result in 3 rows of width 100%

How do i use widths properly in a chrome extension popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to use CSS, you still have to write the classes themselves. Do you have a class in your CSS file that has the name col-md-4? It looks like you are using Twitter Bootstrap, in which case you need to include the CSS file for it and also to make sure that your screen size is wide enough. To include all of Bootstrap and the Javascript functions you can include these three lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```